# Partition function for $N$ particles, $e^{-Ei}$ term also scaled by $N$?

Tags: thermodynamics, partition-function

My professor didn't go over partition functions explicitly including $e^{E_i}$ terms in his lecture notes for some reason.

Do you have to scale the $e^{-E_i/k_{B}T}$ term by $N$ if you have $N$ particles, e.g., $\rightarrow\,e^{-NE_i/k_{B}T}$

Comment: Please, provide more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition function is basically the normalization of the probability distribution. For a system held at constant temperature, the probability to be at a certain energy state is proportional to the Boltzmann factor, i.e. $p(E_i) \propto e^{-\beta E_i}$, where $\beta = \frac{1}{k_BT}$. Notice that $E_i$ is an energy of a certain **state** of the system. The probability $p(E_i)$ is the **probability that the system is in a state with energy $E_i$**.

Since we need the probability to be normalized, we have that $p(E_i) = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i}$, where $Z = \sum\limits_{i}e^{-\beta E_i}$, which we call the partition function.
The summation is over **all possible states of the system**. I stress this point because it is important.

For example, a system with one particle that can have energies either $0,\epsilon$, the partition function will be
$$
Z _1= e^{-\beta\cdot 0} + e^{-\beta\epsilon} = 1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}
$$
For a system with two particles, each can be with energies $0,\epsilon$, we have 4 different states: The two particles are with energy $0$, one with energy $\epsilon$ and the other with energy $0$ (there are two such possibilities), and both with energy $\epsilon$. The corresponding energies are $0,\epsilon,\epsilon,2\epsilon$, and the partition function is
$$
Z _2= 1+e^{-\beta\epsilon} + e^{-\beta\epsilon} + e^{-2\beta\epsilon} = 1+2e^{-\beta\epsilon}+e^{-2\beta\epsilon}
$$
So you see, the number of particles is embedded in the possible states of the system.

Note that in the second example, we have that

$$
Z_2 = (1+e^{-\beta\epsilon})(1+e^{-\beta\epsilon}) = (Z_1)^2
$$
Generally, for $N$ particles with two possible states each, $Z_{tot} = (Z_1)^N$. This is somewhat a general result for non interacting particles.

There is one special case that we do normalize by the number of particles (more correctly, $N!$). This is when the particles are **indistinguishable**. This is called the [Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox).